# Can Spring Cloud Stream TestSupportBinder be used to test a Kafka Streams processor?

Tags: spring, unit-testing, apache-kafka

I am trying to test a Spring Cloud Streams and Kafka Streams application using the provided TestSupportBinder. The example provided in the docs works for me fine:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Fishtown.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#_testing

However there is no example for a Kafka Streams application, and all the examples of testing Kafka Streams applications instead use the more heavyweight embedded Kafka instance integration test:
https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples/tree/master/kafka-streams-samples

Even so, the recommendation for testing Spring Cloud Streams **in general** is to use the Test Binder:
[How to create unit test with kafka embedded in the spring cloud stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43330544/how-to-create-unit-test-with-kafka-embedded-in-the-spring-cloud-stream)

This is what I want to do too, but specifically to test a Kafka Streams application. I do not want to go the embedded Kafka integration test route just yet, and just need unit tests, preferably with broker mocked out via the Test Binder.

### What I've tried so far:

First I started with the working example from the Test Binder docs, and tried simply replacing `@EnableBinding(Processor.class)` with `@EnableBinding(KafkaStreamsProcessor.class)` as below:

```
    @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
    @SpringBootTest(webEnvironment= SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
    public class ExampleTest {

      @Autowired
      private Processor processor;

      @Autowired
      private MessageCollector messageCollector;

      @Test
      @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
      public void testWiring() {
        Message<String> message = new GenericMessage<>("hello");
        processor.input().send(message);
        Message<String> received = (Message<String>) messageCollector.forChannel(processor.output()).poll();
        assertThat(received.getPayload(), equalTo("hello world"));
      }


      @SpringBootApplication
      @EnableBinding(KafkaStreamsProcessor.class)
      public static class MyProcessor {

        @Autowired
        private Processor channels;

        @Transformer(inputChannel = Processor.INPUT, outputChannel = Processor.OUTPUT)
        public KStream<String, String> transform(KStream<String, String> in) {
          return in.map((key, value) -> new KeyValue<>(key, value + " world"));
        }
      }
    }
```

This results in `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.cloud.stream.messaging.Processor` available:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
  at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:125) ~[spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:107) ~[spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117) ~[spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83) ~[spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:44) ~[spring-boot-test-autoconfigure-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:242) ~[spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227) [spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289) [spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
  at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
  at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291) [spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246) [spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97) [spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
  at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61) [spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70) [spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
  at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190) [spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86) [.cp/:na]
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38) [.cp/:na]
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:538) [.cp/:na]
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:760) [.cp/:na]
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:460) [.cp/:na]
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:206) [.cp/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'exampleTest.MyProcessor': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'channels'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.cloud.stream.messaging.Processor' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:587) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:91) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:373) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1344) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:760) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:388) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:138) ~[spring-boot-test-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99) ~[spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:117) ~[spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
  ... 26 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.cloud.stream.messaging.Processor' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1509) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1104) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1065) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:584) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
  ... 45 common frames omitted
```

Second I tried specifying subbing in `@EnableBinding({ Processor.class, KafkaStreamsProcessor.class })`, but this resulted in `Invalid bean definition with name 'output' defined in org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.streams.annotations.KafkaStreamsProcessor: bean definition with this name already exists`:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
      at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:125) ~[spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
      at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:107) ~[spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
      at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117) ~[spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
      at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83) ~[spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
      at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:44) ~[spring-boot-test-autoconfigure-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
      at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:242) ~[spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
      at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227) [spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
      at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289) [spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
      at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
      at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291) [spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
      at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246) [spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
      at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97) [spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
      at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
      at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
      at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
      at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
      at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
      at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61) [spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
      at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70) [spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
      at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
      at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190) [spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
      at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86) [.cp/:na]
      at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38) [.cp/:na]
      at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:538) [.cp/:na]
      at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:760) [.cp/:na]
      at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:460) [.cp/:na]
      at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:206) [.cp/:na]
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean definition with name 'output' defined in org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.streams.annotations.KafkaStreamsProcessor: bean definition with this name already exists - Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.cloud.stream.messaging.Processor; factoryMethodName=output; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null
      at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindingBeanDefinitionRegistryUtils.registerBindingTargetBeanDefinition(BindingBeanDefinitionRegistryUtils.java:64) ~[spring-cloud-stream-2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
      at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindingBeanDefinitionRegistryUtils.registerOutputBindingTargetBeanDefinition(BindingBeanDefinitionRegistryUtils.java:54) ~[spring-cloud-stream-2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
      at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindingBeanDefinitionRegistryUtils.lambda$registerBindingTargetBeanDefinitions$0(BindingBeanDefinitionRegistryUtils.java:86) ~[spring-cloud-stream-2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
      at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:562) ~[spring-core-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
      at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:541) ~[spring-core-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
      at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindingBeanDefinitionRegistryUtils.registerBindingTargetBeanDefinitions(BindingBeanDefinitionRegistryUtils.java:76) ~[spring-cloud-stream-2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
      at org.springframework.cloud.stream.config.BindingBeansRegistrar.registerBeanDefinitions(BindingBeansRegistrar.java:45) ~[spring-cloud-stream-2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
      at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.lambda$loadBeanDefinitionsFromRegistrars$0(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:360) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
      at java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:684) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
      at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsFromRegistrars(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:359) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
      at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:144) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
      at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:117) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
      at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:328) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
      at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:233) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
      at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:273) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
      at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:93) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
      at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:693) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
      at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:531) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
      at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
      at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
      at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:388) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
      at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
      at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:138) ~[spring-boot-test-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
      at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99) ~[spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
      at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:117) ~[spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
      ... 26 common frames omitted
```

Third I tried `@EnableBinding(KafkaStreamsProcessor.class)` again, and replaced the declaration `private Processor processor;` with `private KafkaStreamsProcessor processor;`, but this results in compile errors because this interface does not define the method signatures the Test Binder tests use e.g `processor.input()`.

Is what I'm trying to do possible, or are the embedded Kafka integration tests the only way to go with Spring Cloud Stream and Kafka Streams applications?